# Remove "at" string from wordpress comment date

Tags: date, comment-form, comments-template

I'm using the following code to format the author's comment date and remove the time:

```
function my_change_comment_date_format( $date, $date_format, $comment ) {
    return date( 'd M Y', strtotime( $comment->comment_date ) );
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'my_change_comment_date_format', 10, 3 );

function wpb_remove_comment_time($date, $d, $comment) { 
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
            return;
    } else { 
            return $date;
    }
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_time', 'wpb_remove_comment_time', 10, 3);
```

But now, what I got is in the following format:
**14 Mar 2013 at**

How can I remove the "at" string, at the end of the date?

Comment: And how do you print these comments?

Comment: with predefined function wp_list_comments()

Comment: And do you use any callback function in there?

Comment: No, just using it "as it is". Should I use the callback key with a function, to edit the date? Is it possible to reformat the entire output in that callback?

Comment: [Here is the solution](http://pressfore.com/edit-wordpress-comments-display-time-ago/) of the similar problem.

Comment: @MaxYudin No, I already saw that, it is something like "this comment was posted x hours ago"

Comment: You can edit the code to change the whole date and time string similar way the author did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, the 'at' is coming from the value of `$comment->comment_date`. If that is the case, and since we have to do with string, you could pass it from `str_replace` first, in order to remove the ' at', like:

```
function my_change_comment_date_format( $date, $date_format, $comment ) {
    return date( 'd M Y', strtotime( str_replace(" at", "", $comment->comment_date) ); );
}
```

**Edit**: since the above was not the case, I searched a bit and got the following:

- In your `comments.php` template you probably have a call to `wp_list_comments()`, which without parameters, runs with [defaults](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) . One of the default arguments is the `'walker' => new Walker_Comment()` which construct the html output of the comments. Taking a look at the [Walker_Comment class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_comment/), arround line 300 is the culprit 'at'.

More specifically: `printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s' ), get_comment_date( '', $comment ), get_comment_time() );`, thus getting rid of `get_comment_time()` will still print at.

To alter the output you can make use of a callback function, passed to the `wp_list_comments()`

e.g:1) in the `comments.php` (or in any other template file you want to display the comments)

```
<?php
// Show comments
wp_list_comments( array(
    'callback' => 'not_default_comments'
) );
?>
```

2) In your `functions.php` (or in a seperate file, which you will include in the functions), write the callback code:

```
<?php
function not_default_comments( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    global $post;
    $author_id = $post->post_author;
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
?>
    <li id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <article id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class('clr'); ?>>
            <div class="comment-author vcard">
                <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 45 ); ?>
            </div><!-- .comment-author -->
            <div class="comment-details clr">
                <header class="comment-meta">
                    <cite class="fn"><?php comment_author_link(); ?></cite>
                    <span class="comment-date">
                    <?php printf( '<a href="%1$s"><time datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a>',
                        esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
                        get_comment_time( 'c' ),
                        sprintf( _x( '%1$s', '1: date', 'twenties' ), get_comment_date() )
                    ); ?>
                    </span><!-- .comment-date -->
                </header><!-- .comment-meta -->
                <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                    <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'twenties' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="comment-content entry clr">
                    <?php comment_text(); ?>
                </div><!-- .comment-content -->
                <div class="reply comment-reply-link">
                    <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array(
                        'reply_text' => esc_html__( 'Reply to this message', 'twenties' ),
                        'depth'      => $depth,
                        'max_depth'  => $args['max_depth'] )
                    ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .reply -->
            </div><!-- .comment-details -->
        </article><!-- #comment-## -->
    <?php
}
```

- I got the above example callback function from [wpexplorer.com](https://www.wpexplorer.com/better-wordpress-comments/), and sligtly modified it to exclude the '... at time' part.

And that's it. Now your comments will be displayed with your custom template from the callback you have provided.

Comment: It does not change the output, after string replace method....

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much easier with JavaScript if you want:

```
const commentsTime = document.querySelectorAll("#comments time")
commentsTime?.forEach(el => {
    el.innerText = el.innerText.replace("at", "")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another bit hacky solution is to first echo the date and then return 'false' with the `get_comment_date` filter:

```
function custom_comment_date( $date, $d, $comment ) {
    echo date( 'd M Y', strtotime( $comment->comment_date ) );
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'custom_comment_date', 10, 3);
```

And then hide "at" with CSS:

```
.comment-meta > a:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```